# Highlight elements in the list using pattern matching

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Starting from the following `list`:

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}};
```

I want to highlight elements in `list` whose intersection is greater than 2.

The following code cannot get the result I want:

```
list //. 
   {{a___, x:{_, _, _}, b___, y:{_, _, _}, c___} /; 
      Length@Intersection[x, y] >= 2 :> 
         {a, Style[x, Gray], b, Style[y, Gray], c}}
```

[image: obtained result, with second, third, fifth, sixth elements highlighted]

The desired result is
[image: desired result, with only second and third elements highlighted]

I also considered `Gather`, but it will change the order of the list.

**Updated:**
I thought of a way, not elegant

```
list //. {a___,x:({_,_,_}|F[{_,_,_}]),b___,y:({_,_,_}),c___}/;
  Length[Intersection[x/.F->Identity,y]]>=2:>{a,F@x,b,F@y,c}
% /. F->Highlighted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rg = RelationGraph[UnsameQ @ ## && Length@Intersection[##] >= 2 &, list]
```

[image]

```
hl = VertexList @ EdgeList @ rg
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}
> ```

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ hl :> Style[x, Gray]
```

[image]

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ hl :> Highlighted[x, BaseStyle -> Red]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
HighlightGraph[rg, hl]
```

[image]

You can also use [`ConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) and select components with more than 1 vertex:

```
ccs = Select[Length @ # >= 2 &] @ ConnectedComponents[rg]
```

> ```
>  {{{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}}
> ```

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ # :> Highlighted[x, BaseStyle -> Red]& /@ ccs
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[formatList]
formatList[list_] := Module[{rules},
  rules =
    AssociationThread[
      list -> (If[Max[#] >= 2, Gray, Black] & /@ 
        Function[{element}, 
          Length@Intersection[element, #] & /@ 
           Complement[list, {element}]] /@ list)
    ];
  Style[#, rules[#]] & /@ list
]

formatList[list]
```

[image: formatted list]

Answer (score 2):

A variant of OP's solution that avoids nesting of  `Highlighted`:

```
list //. {a___, x : ({_, _, _} | Highlighted[{_, _, _}, ___]), b___, 
    y : ({_, _, _}), c___} /; Length[Intersection[x /. Highlighted -> (# &), y]] >= 2 :> 
   {a, Highlighted[x /. Highlighted -> (# &)], b, Highlighted@y, c}
```

[image]

Same approach using `Style`:

```
list //. {a___, x : ({_, _, _} | Style[{_, _, _}, ___]), b___, 
    y : ({_, _, _}), c___} /; Length[Intersection[x /. Style -> (# &), y]] >= 2 :> 
   {a, Style[x /. Style -> (# &), Gray], b, Style[y /. Style -> (# &), Gray], c}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easy way is still use `Gather` and reorder the index. Here we handle the general situation.

```
SeedRandom[400];
list = Table[RandomSample[Alphabet[], 3], 40];
newlist = Thread[Range[Length@list] -> list];
result = Gather[newlist, 
   Length[Intersection[Last@#1, Last@#2]] >= 2 &];
keys = Keys /@ result;
keyc = Thread[keys -> RandomColor[Length@keys]]
map[j_] := 
  MapAt[Style[#, Last@keyc[[j]], Bold] &, List /@ First@keyc[[j]]];
fig = Composition[Sequence @@ Table[map[j], {j, 1, Length@keyc}]]@
  list
Grid[Partition[fig, 8], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
list /. x : {__Symbol} /; 
  Max[Length[Intersection[x, #]] & /@ DeleteCases[list, x]] >= 2 :> 
    Style[x, Gray]
```

[image]

A method using `GatherBy`:

```
gb = Join @@ Select[Length@# > 1 &]@
   GatherBy[list, Function[x, Max[Length[Intersection[x, #]] & /@ DeleteCases[x][list]]]]
```

> ```
>  {{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}
> ```

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ gb :> Style[x, Gray]
```

[image]

#### Why `Gather` does not work:

Taking a simpler example:

```
list2 = Partition[Range@5, 3, 1];
GatherBy[list2, Function[x, Max[Length[Intersection[x, #]] & /@ 
  DeleteCases[x][list2]] >= 2]]
```

> ```
>  {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}}}
> ```

```
Gather[list2, Length[Intersection[##]] >= 2 &]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}},
>  {{3, 4, 5}}}
> ```

`Gather` does not perform the test function on all pairs of the input list. If the test function evaluates to `True` for the pair `{p1, p2}` (so that `p1` and `p2` are grouped together) then the pair `{p1, p3}` is tested but `{p2, p3}` is skipped as can be seen in `Trace` output:

```
Trace[Gather[list2, Length[Intersection[##]] >= 2 &]] // Rest // Rest // Column
```

[image]

Note that the triples `{2, 3, 4}` and `{3, 4, 5}` are *not compared* (because `{2, 3, 4}` is *already gathered*}.

Comment: Thank you!   Until today I know that `Gather` must using ** equivalence relation** ,and `Intersection[##]] >= 2 ` is not such relation. I think I need time to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}};

sub = Subsets[list, {2}];
```

---

Another variant of @kglr's solution using `Counts` and `Pick` is the following:

```
F = Length@Values@Select[Counts @@ List@*Join @@ #, # >= 2 &] >= 2 &;

highlighted = Union @@ Pick[#, F /@ #] &@sub
```

> `{{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}`

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ highlighted :> Style[x, Bold, Red]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is to take the `Union` of 2-subsets that satisfy the condition:

```
highlighted = Union @@ Select[Length[Intersection @@ #] >= 2 &] @ Subsets[list, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}
> ```

```
list /. x : Alternatives @@ highlighted :> Style[x, Gray]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}};

sub = Subsets[list, {2}];
```

Using `SymmetricDifference` (new in 13.1)

```
res = 
 Union @ Catenate @ Extract[Position[SymmetricDifference @@@ sub, {_, _}]] @ sub
```

{{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}

Using `UniqueElements` (new in 13.1)

```
res = 
 Union @ Catenate @ Extract[Position[UniqueElements /@ sub, {{_}, {_}}]] @ sub
```

{{a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {c, a, m}, {c, d, n}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) to highlight

```
ReplaceAt[a_ :> Style[a, Blue], Position[list, Alternatives @@ res]] @ list
```

[image]